# button 2 displays same text as the button1 display

Tags: javascript, html

I made a button that displays some text then I wanted to create a second button but I had an issue ; which is if I click on the second button it displays what the first button must display :

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
          <button class="button1" onclick="myFunction()">I want it !</button>
        </div>
    
    <p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 30px;color: ivory;" id="demo"></p>
    
    <script>
      var hulu ="huluexample6969@gmail.com";
      
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hulu;
    
    var hbo ="hboexample6969@gmail.com"
     document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hbo;
    }
    
    </script>
    
    <h4 style="padding-top: 80px;padding-left: 60px; color: green;">HBO:</h4>
     <div class="hbo">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1212600271328530436/XrpOrfrt_400x400.jpg"
     </div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
      <button class="button2" onclick="myFunction()">I want it !</button>
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: left;padding-top: 30px;color: ivory;" id="demo2"></p>
```

Comment: Both buttons are calling `myFunction()`. Is this on purpose?

Comment: so I need to change the name ?

Comment: what do you want the second button to do that's different from the first button? Do you want the first button to display hulu and the second to display hbo?

Comment: Exactly . But thnx I've solved it . I needed to change the function name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with one function just use a if statement

```js
var hulu ="huluexample6969@gmail.com";

function myFunction(e) {

if (e.target.className == 'button1'){
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hulu;
}else{
var hbo ="hboexample6969@gmail.com"
 document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hbo;
}}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <button class="button1" onclick="myFunction(event)">I want it !</button>
    </div>

<p style="text-align: center;padding-top: 30px;color: blue;" id="demo">aaaaa</p>


<h4 style="padding-top: 80px;padding-left: 60px; color: green;">HBO:</h4>
 <div class="hbo">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1212600271328530436/XrpOrfrt_400x400.jpg">
 </div>
<div class="wrapper2">
  <button class="button2" onclick="myFunction(event)">I want it !</button>
</div>
<p style="text-align: left;padding-top: 30px;color: blue;" id="demo2">bbbb</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, whether I understand your issue correctly.

From what I can tell, both `<button>`s have `onclick="myFunction()"`, which make them execute

```
var hulu ="huluexample6969@gmail.com";

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hulu;

  var hbo ="hboexample6969@gmail.com"
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hbo;
}
```

So both will manipulate the `<p>`s with ID "demo" resp. "demo2".

What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: So I need to change the function name ?

Comment: I think, you want two separate functions:

`function updateDemo1 () { var hulu ="huluexample6969@gmail.com"; document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hulu; }` and `function updateDemo2 () { var hbo ="hboexample6969@gmail.com"; document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hbo; }`.

Comment: thnx for the tip  . I changed the second function name and it worked